# how to add an artifact to maven repository

Tags: android, maven, maven-central

I do not know anything about maven. Recently I downloaded a Android project code and it included pom.xml file. So after searching for hours  I manages to properly import it as a maven project. Every thing seems pretty error free but for one item.

> Missing artifact org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map:jar:0.3.0

So I looked at my

> C:\Users\MWH.m2\repository\org\mapsforge\mapsforge-map\0.3.0

where all of my artifacts are stored. But there is no executable jar file for this mapsforge-map jar. How can I add this jar to this maven project if it is not available in my repository?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just delete the folder '$HOME/.m2/repository/org/mapsforge' and start an other time via 'mvn clean package'. Are you sitting behind a proxy/firewall?

Answer (score 3):

[Three special steps](http://youtu.be/uWLu9fPQoiM?t=25s):

1. Download the jar file (from https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/downloads/list ?)
2. Copy the jar file to your local Maven repository:

   ```
   mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.mapsforge -DartifactId=mapsforge-map -Dversion=0.3.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=mapsforge-map-0.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
   ```

   *(in the directory you stored the `jar` file)*
3. Do `mvn compile` in your project folder to verify the newly-installed dependency is available.

Comment: how can I change the default repo location from  http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 to http://mc-repo.googlecode.com/svn/maven2/thirdparty/ ?

Comment: No need to change the defaults, you can easily add a new Maven repository in `pom.xml`: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories

Answer (score 0):

If it is not available in your repository run the "mvn:clean package" command.Maven will automatically download the dependecy for you.

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project osmdroid-third-party: Could not resolv
e dependencies for project org.osmdroid:osmdroid-third-party:jar:3.0.8: The foll
owing artifacts could not be resolved: com.google.android.maps:maps:jar:3_r3, or
g.mapsforge:mapsforge-map:jar:0.3.0: Failure to find com.google.android.maps:map
s:jar:3_r3 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local reposi
tory, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central ha
s elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Comment: so how do I do if the above artifacts are not found in the central repository?